# Bevel sharp corners

Tags: modeling, bevel

When I bevel the corners of this object, they overlap each other.
Any suggestions how to prevent this?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Using bevel modifier with edge weight to prevent this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The bevel modifier works now, after separating the loose parts. But the modifier won't go further than a very small edge, because of the overlapping. I will attach the blendfile in the main question.

Comment: I don't need it myself anymore, but I think this is a solution for some! https://www.blendernation.com/2020/05/23/free-blender-add-on-straight-skeleton/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe try to apply the scale and then try to bevel again?

If it doesn't works try to select the edges in edge mode with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> and then try again.

Comment: Hi Mahmut, thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that, but sadly doesn't work. The addon I placed as an answer to my own question does work for this problem.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know. I am happy that you solved your problem.